# ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch (dynamic image uploader)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes, image-uploading

I am trying to follow the tutorial *[Dynamic multiple image uploads with Ruby on Rails](http://shiningthrough.co.uk/Dynamic-multiple-image-uploads-with-Ruby-on-Rails)* that creates a new model for photos and will associate them with another model. After copying and pasting all the code I'm getting an "AssociationTypeMismatch" error as follows.

```
 ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in AdminForksController#update
 Photo(#2176152540) expected, got Array(#2148417160)
 app/controllers/admin_forks_controller.rb:23:in `update'
 {   "commit"=>"update",
     "fork"=>{"position"=>"",
              "name"=>"FORK",
              "brand"=>"",
               "photos"=>{"data"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x103634328 @headers="Content-
               Disposition: form-data; name=\"fork[photos][data]\"; filename=\"marty.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type:
               image/jpeg\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/cZ/cZVO8X55FeynZw5cHRz1UE+++TI
               /-Tmp/RackMultipart20110716-18721-16ttjsd-0>, @content_type="image/jpeg",
               @original_filename="marty.jpg">},
     "authenticity_token"=>"iSzZxyzTe/LDLIf4cQiYBGLIk96INnKCP3SC5b5MXHw=",
     "utf8"=>"?",
     "id"=>"7"}
```

My forks model looks like this:

```
class Fork < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :photos
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

And my photos model looks like this:

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :fork
    has_attached_file :data
end
```

It looks like `:photos` is getting passed as an array, and `:fork` is expecting it. How do I resolve this issue?

**Update**

The issue was resolved (see the answer). However, how do the two variables, `:fork` and `@fork`, differ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved. In my `for_for` I was using `:fork` instead of `@fork`.