# "Association type mismatch "? In paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I am using paperclip to upload user avatar.Evrery thing work well but when i hit the save button i got the error :

```
    ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in UsersController#update

    Usernote(#79841148) expected, got Array(#25890648)

    Request

Parameters:

{"authenticity_token"=>"bLhGiceEIEohpuuclDpbmpzJR7SFb4HEY4+Qy9ER20E=",
 "_method"=>"put",
 "utf8"=>"✓",
 "id"=>"2",
 "user"=>{"user_information"=>{"passport_number"=>"",
 "passport_expiry_date"=>"",
 "gender"=>"Male",
 "birth_date"=>"",
 "marriage_date"=>"",
 "present_address"=>"",
 "blood_group"=>"",
 "emergency_contact"=>"",
 "marital_status"=>"Married"},
 "usernotes"=>{"notes"=>"Hi this is First note from Ritz"},
 "designation_id"=>"2",
 "username"=>"ritz",
 "reporting_to_id"=>"",
 "avatar"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x9514578 @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user[avatar]\"; filename=\"child ravi.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n",
 @content_type="image/jpeg",
 @original_filename="child ravi.jpg",
 @tempfile=#<File:C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp/RackMultipart20111207-2300-3nkxr9-0>>,
 "last_name"=>"roshan",
 "user_salary_detail"=>{"work_phone"=>"",
 "EPS_account_number"=>"",
 "work_type"=>"Permanent",
 "date_of_joining"=>"",
 "work_location"=>"",
 "branch"=>"",
 "PF_account_number"=>"",
 "bank_name"=>"",
 "PAN"=>"",
 "status"=>"Active",
 "bank_account_number"=>""},
 "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "department_id"=>"1",
 "first_name"=>"hritwik",
 "email"=>"rvdthakur@yahoo.com"}}
```

Here is My Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_attached_file :avatar,
                    :styles => {
                      :thumb => "75x75#",
                      :small => "100x100#",
                      :medium => "150x150>"
                    },
                    :default => :thumb,
                    :url => "/users/user_avatar/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",  
                    :path => ":profitnext/public/images/users/user_avatar/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"  

# avatar validations
  validates_attachment_size :avatar, :less_than => 5.megabytes
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/png'] 
end
```

and My View:

```
<%= image_tag @user.avatar.url %>
              <%= image_tag @user.avatar.url(:thumb) %>
```

I got that error after hitting save button.I am struggling with this a lot.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that this is nothing to do with paperclip but is more along the lines of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718779/activerecordassociationtypemismatch-dynamic-image-uploader). Do you have a `has_many :usernotes` in your User model and/or a `belongs_to :user` in your Usernote model?

Comment: Thanks for replay Ramblex  I have a usernote table and same association you are talking about.But this is not came earlier

Comment: Hi i deleted that "usernotes" field for now but got "missing missing" at instead of "avatar" field ,what i am missing? please help me.

Comment: What's the exact error you're getting? Do you see this error when you submit the form?

Comment: No at the form submission i got the success message, and here at view page i see "missing" text at "<%= image_tag @user.avatar.url %>
              <%= image_tag @user.avatar.url(:thumb) %>"

Comment: Do you have attr_accessible in your user model? Make sure that you have :avatar in your attr_accessible list.

Comment: I commented that b'coz i got "Undefined method :url" for <%= image_tag @user.avatar.url %>